# $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} a_{mn}=\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{mn}=0$ implies $a_{nn} \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The question is as in the title.

Let us suppose that a double sequence $(a_{mn})$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} a_{mn}=\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{mn}=0
\end{equation}

Then, I wonder if the "diagonal" sequence $(a_{nn})$ tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$:
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{nn}=0
\end{equation}

I tried to justify this myself but it seems more confusing than expected. Could anyone plese help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this implication is false.  Consider $a_{nn}=1$, $a_{nm}=0$ for $m\neq n$.

Answer (score 2):

$a_{nm}=e^{-|n-m|}$ is a counterexample